# Angular testing: tick vs flushMicrotasks in fakeAsync block

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, angular-test

As far as my understanding goes from reading the [Angular testing docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-utility-apis), calling `tick()` flushes both (supported) macro tasks, and micro-task queues within the `fakeAsync` block. In which case, under the hood, I assume, calling `tick()` will be the same as having some additional calls + calling `flushMicrotasks()`.

Question is, is there any case where I should use:

```
it('should pass', fakeAsync(() => {
  // given some setup...

  doSomethingAsynchronous();
  flushMicrotasks();

  // do some assertions...
}));
```

instead of

```
it('should pass', fakeAsync(() => {
  // given some setup...

  doSomethingAsynchronous();
  tick();

  // do some assertions...
}));
```

❓

Answer (score 4):

Excerpt from the article [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/microtask-and-macrotask-a-hands-on-approach-5d77050e2168).

> macrotasks are enqueued by setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate, etc.
>   microtasks by process.nextTick, Promises, MutationObserver, etc.

So if you are using setTimeouts, setInterval etc then use tick() and if you are using some promises, then you can use either tick() or flushMicrotasks().